# Unable to call webservice function angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Unable to call webservice function from angularjs controller.
It is accessing the file but function is not accessible.
Errors:

> 1. server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
>    2. System.InvalidOperationException:Web Service method name is not valid.    at
>         System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()    at
>         System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type,
>         HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,
>         Boolean& abortProcessing)

```
namespace AngularJSTesting.App{

    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService2 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TextItConnectionString"].ToString();



        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string FetchData()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select UserName, Name, Email, PhoneNumber from new_users where UserId < 11 order by UserId asc ", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                    Dictionary<string, object> row;
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                        }
                        rows.Add(row);
                    }
                    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
                }
            }
        }

        [WebMethod]
       // [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string read()
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }
    }
```

js file

```
'use strict';

app.controller('aboutController', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.message = "Now viewing About!";

var url = 'WebService2.asmx/read';
$http.get(url)
           .success(function (data) {
               alert("success");
               $scope.users = data;

           })
           .error(function (data) {
               alert("error");
               alert(data);
           })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [Script Method Get Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.usehttpget(v=vs.110).aspx) `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]` to web method.
Also remove `static` from function signature.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public string read()
{
    return "test";
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadTauseen Did you try removing `static` keyword

Comment: Yes. 
Found the solution; cannot access the functions of webservice without deploying it

Comment: No Words to say. You should have considered it very first.